# How to show button based on the page you are coming from, Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have home page that lists items, but also when I add an item I want to popToRoot(), to home page. Now, If I come to root from addItemPage, I want to show the button to save a list, to make a HTTP call..

Is it possible, I was thinking about passing the for example (fromAdd: true) to navCtrl and then based on that show the button(ngIf) ?

Comment: You can pass route params and check them to render the button or not

Comment: If you are using the navController you can get the current view name easily. Create a service or provider which gives you the name and use this service/provider in your menu.

Comment: I passed the bolean with the `NavController`, thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the rootscope variables, navparams and service to set the value on the parent page and then access it in your ng-init function declared on you child page and show your button on the basis of that value by using ngIf expression.

Comment: I did something like that..Thank you :)